# Fortran epsilon function equivalent in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm starting to learn Julia, and I was wondering if there is an equivalent function in Julia that is doing the same as the epsilon function in Fortran.

In Fortran, the epsilon function of variable `x` gives the smallest number of the same kind of `x` that satisfies `1+epsilon(x)>1`

I thought the the function `eps()` in Julia would be something similar, so I tried

```
eps(typeof(x))
```

but I got the error:

```
MethodError: no method matching eps(::Type{Int64})
```

Is there any other function that resembles the Fortran one that can be used on the different variables of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docstring for `eps` says:

```
help?> eps

  eps(::Type{T}) where T<:AbstractFloat
  eps()
```

`eps` is only defined for subtypes of `AbstractFloat` i.e. floating point numbers. It seems that your variable `x` is an integer variable, as the error message says `no method matching eps(::Type{Int64})`. It doesn't really make sense to define an `eps` for integers since the "the smallest number of the same kind of x that satisfies `1 + epsilon(x) > 1`" is always going to be 1 for integers.

If you did want to get a `1` of the specific type of integer you have, you can use the `one` function instead:

```
julia> x = UInt8(42)
0x2a

julia> one(typeof(x))
0x01
```

Comment: Does `?eps` really only list those two methods? The wanted functionality appears to be provided by the next method, `eps(x::AbstractFloat)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need `eps` to work for both `Float` and `Int` types, you can overload a method of `eps` for `Int` by writing `Base.eps(Int) = one(Int)`. Then your code will work. This is okay for personal projects, but not a good idea for code you intend to share.

Comment: For details on why this is a bad idea on any serious code, see the [section on type piracy in the Juila manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Avoid-type-piracy).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you actually want is

```
eps(x)
```

*not*

```
eps(typeof(x))
```

The former is exactly equivalent to your Fortran function.

Comment: Though the call looks similar, `eps(x)` in Julia does something different from Fortran's `EPSILON(X)`. The Fortran function is defined to be what the OP mentioned in their question, "the smallest number E of the same kind as X such that 1 + E > 1". In Julia, that is provided by `eps(typeof(x))`. `eps(x)` returns the epsilon value **at x**, not **at 1** as the Fortran function does.

Comment: Both methods have their use though, the decision depends on what the returned value is being used for.

Comment: You are right. But what a strange choice in Fortran. I would never have imagined that `epsilon(x)` didn't use the value of `x`. I shall edit my post in a while.